# Why is my 200 amp home electrical box in the wall being supplied with only 100 amps from the pole/meter?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm renting a trailer thats causing problems with my major applianes. I discover that my 209 amp box inside the home is only being supplied with 100 amps from the pole. Could tghe was my landlord has it wired be the problem or hazardous bc I will fix it my self if that's what his electrician does.

Comment: how do you know it is supplied with 100 amps from the pole?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what problems you are actually having with your appliances, and if you spent a little more time making sure your writing is clear.  At least check for typos.  209 amp?  Could tghe?   Help us help you by writing clearly.

Comment: You're renting. You're not legally allowed (In the US) to do electrical work on this property. The landlord isn't either. He must hire a licensed electrician to do the work.

Comment: Could you clarify "renting a trailer" and where the 200a panel is in relation to this trailer. Does "trailer" mean a mobile home that you're living in? Is it some sort of RV trailer that you've got plugged into "shore power" (i.e. your hose), and, therefore, there could be an issue in the trailer itself that's causing problems in the house? Is it some sort of other trailer that is, somehow, drawing power from the residence and is causing issues? Lots of possibilities here...

Comment: @FreeMan yes, but you're legally allowed to watch out for common utility-side problems, and welcome to call the utility to have them fix their wires.

Answer (score 7):

The panel's amp rating is a maximum.  The main breaker (if equipped) will likely match the capacity of the panel buss but doesn't have to.

By the same token, the circuit serving the panel doesn't have to match the amperage of the panel.  The panel just has to be rated for *at least* that.  A 200A panel being fed with a 100A service is not uncommon.  You can feed a 400A panel with a 30A service if you want.

FWIW, the amperage rating of the panel isn't likely to be the cause of your appliance problems.

Answer (score 5):

200A is just a redline "never exceed" maximum rating. It's fine for any service <=200A.   They're like 130 mph tires.

The advantage to 200A panels is they have more spaces for more circuit breakers. Also they are often on sale, and often come with free breakers.

**100A is plenty of power for a manufactured home** and I can't see why you're having problems unless you have unusual loads, like pool, **tankless** water heater, huge EV charger etc.  Try turning off every circuit breaker 30A or larger, except for range. Does that clear things up?

Have you considered the possibility that maybe something is actually wrong with your power supply from the utility? That happens all the time - you have 3 wires and if 1 breaks, a bunch of weird stuff will happen.  Try describing in detail the effects you are actually observing, instead of your feelings about it.  Does turning on the oven seem to fix totally unrelated problems? Does running a hair dryer or toaster make things worse?  Are you running 2 space heaters?

Answer (score 2):

The power company does not install transformers and supply current based on the panel size. They install what they "think" you need based on the area being served. If they're wrong and the transformer blows a fuse, they'll investagate and make necessary changes.

Comment: If the "trailer" being rented is a mobile home, I'd think that a 200a panel is actually quite rather large for that application. Not enough experience with mobile homes to know for certain, though.

Comment: @FreeMan For a trailer, you're right.  I deleted thhe statement.

Comment: Then again, as I noted in my comment on the question, maybe the "trailer" is an RV/caravan/5th-wheel that's simply plugged into shore power. Need more details from the OP.